# Fortran: Allocatable array of derived type containing an array of derived type

Tags: gdb, fortran, derived-types, allocatable-array

I am currently working on a large Fortran program where I have a discrete numerical grid that contains a series of particles that I track within the bounds of the grid. To do this I have defined the following three derived types:

```
type :: particle
    real(pr), dimension(3) :: r = 0.0_pr ! position
    real(pr), dimension(3) :: p = 0.0_pr ! momentum
end type particle

type :: rcell ! position cell
    integer, dimension(6) :: bpoints = 0 ! cell grid points
    integer :: np = 0 ! number of particles in cell
    type(particle), dimension(50) :: parts ! particles in cell
end type rcell

type :: pcell ! momentum cell
    integer, dimension(6) :: bpoints = 0 ! cell grid points
    integer :: np = 0 ! number of particles in cell
end type pcell

...

type(rcell), dimension(:), allocatable :: rbin ! position space bins
type(pcell), dimension(:), allocatable :: pbin ! momentum space bins

...

allocate(rbin(100))
allocate(pbin(100))
```

First of all, is this an acceptable use of derived types (i.e. having an allocatable array of a derived type that contains an array of a derived type)? The code compiles fine using gfortran 4.8.3.

However, I encounter some strange issues when trying to debug the code using gdb 7.7.1 under Fedora. When trying to look at the data in an element of the `rbin` array (using `print rbin(10)%bpoints` for example) gdb always prints out `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` even though I have assigned data to `bpoints` (e.g. `rbin(10)%bpoints = (/1,2,1,2,1,2/)`). If I look at the data in an element of the `pbin` array using `print pbin(10)%bpoints` for example, then I get exactly what I expect. Does anyone have some insight on this issue?

Comment: First of all, yes, I agree with the compiler that what you have written is syntactically correct.  If it does what you want, then why not regard it as acceptable ?  The `gdb` issues looks like just that to me, a `gdb` issue.  Several debuggers I've used recently (I haven't used `gdb` for a very long time) have had trouble displaying the contents of Fortran allocatables.

Comment: I was mostly wondering if I may run into issues down the line using this type of structure (e.g. when passing portions of it to subroutines). From past experience, just because it compiles does not necessarily mean it will behave as expected. In regards to gdb, it is just a gdb issue. I tried this morning with the Intel debugger (idb 13.0) and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these kinds of structures in my code all the time. No problem compiling or running under on linux-like OS using gfortran. The intel compiler had issues with this type of code 5 years ago, but I have moved away from that compiler lately so I'm not sure if they've caught up to the newer Fortran standards now. I use MPI, so I can rarely use gdb and can't be helpful about why its throwing errors.

Anyway, I agree with Mark; modern Fortran (compiled using gfortran) can handle this type of structure just fine.

Comment: I second this. I had issues in the past with Intel and complicated structures but in recent times it seems to have improved a lot.